# EmailMessage failing to insert occasionally

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, developer, emailfileattachment

I have written some apex code to create a case when an email is sent to the support email. It's working great but sometimes when a customer sends an email with attachments the attachments get inserted but not the email message. Below is my code for inserting the email.

```
    public static EmailMessage InsertEmailMessage(Messaging.inboundEmail email, Case c){
    System.debug('Inserting Email');
    em = new EmailMessage();
    string toaddress = string.join(email.toAddresses,',');
    em.ToAddress = toaddress;
    em.Subject = email.subject;
    em.TextBody = email.plainTextBody;
    em.FromAddress = email.replyTo;
    em.HtmlBody = email.htmlBody;
    em.ParentId = c.Id;
    em.Incoming = true;
    em.FromName = email.fromName;

    // Save attachments, if any
    List<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();
    if(email.textAttachments != null)
    {
        for (Messaging.Inboundemail.TextAttachment tAttachment : email.textAttachments) {
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
            attachment.Name = tAttachment.fileName;
            attachment.Body = Blob.valueOf(tAttachment.body);
            attachment.ParentId = c.Id;
            attachments.add(attachment);
        }
    }
    if(email.binaryAttachments != null)
    {
        for (Messaging.Inboundemail.BinaryAttachment bAttachment : email.binaryAttachments) {
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
            
            attachment.Name = bAttachment.fileName;
            attachment.Body = bAttachment.body;
            attachment.ParentId = c.Id;
            attachments.add(attachment);
        }
    }
    if(attachments.size() > 0)
    {
        insert attachments;
    }
    
    insert em;
    return em;
}
```

What would cause EmailMessage to be randomly not inserting the email message? I was unable to reproduce the issue but we have received more than one complain.

Comment: By saying `I was unable to reproduce the issue`, do you mean you have been able to identify emails (pointed out by end user) that has this issue and using the same email doesn't cause this problem?

Comment: @arut -  I thought that this was related to the user having send the email from outlook so I tried to send an email using outlook and everything worked fine.

Comment: You should incorporate some exception handling in the code (in case this issue reoccurs).

Comment: The issue is still there for the customer I just haven't been able to reproduce it myself

Comment: So did you get the email from the user & use it? or, just try an email from your end? Is this user having problem on all the emails he/she sends (could be a permission issue?)?